# How to connect to external PRIMARY LDAP server WSO2IS 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to set up an external LDAP (openldap-2.4.31) server with WSO2IS, for that I have changed some configuration in deployment.toml here is the sample of my configuration:

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "password"
create_admin_account = false


[user_store]
class = "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager"
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
connection_url = "ldap://my.url.com:389"
connection_name = "cn=admin,DC=url,DC=com"
connection_password = "password"
user_search_base = "DC=url,DC=com"
base_dn = "DC=url,DC=com"
read_groups = false
```

I already have set up for the LDAP server and admin user is in the base dn.

Whenever I try to connect to the server I get the following error message:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.internal.SCIMCommonComponent} - Error occurred while setting SCIM attributes for the Admin org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in adding SCIM metadata to the admin in tenant domain: carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.utils.SCIMCommonUtils.setAdminSCIMAttributes(SCIMCommonUtils.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.internal.SCIMCommonComponent.activate(SCIMCommonComponent.java:79)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.internal.IdentityCoreServiceComponent.activate(IdentityCoreServiceComponent.java:171)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:305)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:973)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 30007 - UserNotFound: User admin does not exist in: PRIMARY
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:205)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1548)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim.common.utils.SCIMCommonUtils.setAdminSCIMAttributes(SCIMCommonUtils.java:231)
        ... 50 more
    Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:191)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:194)
        ... 54 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: 30007 - UserNotFound: User admin does not exist in: PRIMARY
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1575)
        ... 59 more
```

I also get this message prior of getting above error:

```
INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} - LDAP connection created successfully in read-write mode
```

Below is my user-mgt.xml:

```
<Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                <UserName>admin</UserName>
                <Password>password</Password>
            </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>

            <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
            <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
            <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
            <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/SHARED_DB</Property>
        </Configuration>
        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="IsBulkImportSupported">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="defaultRealmName">WSO2.ORG</Property>
            <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
            <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">password</Property>
            <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"></Property>
            <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">DC=url,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="StartTLSEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserIdSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
            <Property name="UserIDAttribute">scimId</Property>
            <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
            <Property name="AnonymousBind">false</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://my.url.com:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,DC=url,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._\-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,DC=url,DC=com</Property>
            <Property name="ReadGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionRetryDelay">120000</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">identityPerson</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 5 to 30 characters</Property>
            <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Username pattern policy violated</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="SCIMEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
            <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
        <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
```

Also when i try changing the [super_admin] config to :

```
create_admin_account = true
```

it also results in error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.addDomainToName(UserCoreUtil.java:561)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addToUserNameCache(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11877)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNameFromUserID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11842)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNamesFromUserIDs(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11916)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddRoleWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1270)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8410)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)
    ... 30 more

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} - Cannot start User Manager Core bundle org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:318)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.addDomainToName(UserCoreUtil.java:561)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addToUserNameCache(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11877)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNameFromUserID(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11842)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserNamesFromUserIDs(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:11916)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doAddRoleWithID(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1270)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8410)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(UniqueIDReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:122)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Brief beginner question of understanding. Why should you set up an external LDAP as the primary user store?
To what extent are the possibilities of a secondary store restricted?

Comment: @Sven, even though this should be asked as a separate question, it is not recommended to use the built-in LDAP server in the production. Because some users are directly created in the Primary without your control. (Tenant admins for example) And this embedded LDAP is not-reliable and prone to corrupt. You may end up in inaccessible tenants. Even the carbon super admin entry. Always use a external LDAP or a JDBC for the Primary user store.

Answer (score 0):

According to your user-mgt.xml file, UserIDAttribute is set to scimId. I think openLdap doesn't have an attribute named scimId.

Change it a unique user attribute that supports in open leap.

```
<Property name="UserIDAttribute">scimId</Property>
```

you can refer [1] for more details on how to configure properties using deployment.toml file.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/setup/configuring-a-read-write-ldap-user-store/

Cheers,
Isura.

Comment: I have tried changing it to 'uid' which is available in OpenLDAP which didn't work for me, I also tried using 'cn'.